# Java Websockets and Autobahn comparison for native Android app

Tags: java, android, websocket, autobahn

I'm trying to decide on a technology to implement Websockets in a native Android application. I've come across the following technologies:

- Java Websockets
- Autobahn

I'm new to programming in Websockets and I'm unsure of what the difference is between Java Websockets and Autobahn for Android. Could someone explain what is possible with the one technology and not with the other? Is one of the two more robust regarding making connections? How well documented are the two of these?

If it's of any importance, I plan on implementing the backend for my Android application in Scala using the Play Framework.

Comment: Autobahn is an implementation of Java Websockets, but it also implements the Web Application Messaging Protocol

Comment: AutobahnAndroid is also specialized for Android, e.g. it will do any networking activity on background threads - since you are simply not allowed to do any on the UI thread on Android.